# Vuetify: get months under each other

Tags: css, datepicker, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm making a date picker website and I'm using Vuetify as a library with Nuxt.js. I want to have months under each other, like this:

[Months under each other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7TfS.png)

But now I get the same month twice (November, November), instead of listing 'September', 'October', 'November' et cetera.. How can I achieve this with Vuetify?

Comment: Are you only getting the same month name or dates as well?

Comment: Yes! I'm getting only november and not the upcoming months :)

Comment: I would recommend providing a code snippet of the issue or answer your own question if you have solved it. Adding a code snippet would also encourage other users to explore solutions for your problem